# Multitype stl map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl

Recently I have started using [this JSON library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json). It has a [nice method](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_ad6a18403e7fbac9c4efd06facc71fc88.html#ad6a18403e7fbac9c4efd06facc71fc88) that allows to get any kind of data and the value will be cast automatically on return, eg:

When using the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Stackoverflow",
  "integer": 1234,
  "precise": 21.24
}
```

We can get different return types using this method:

```
json config = json::parse(buf);

std::cout << typeid(config.value("integer", 0)).name() << std::endl; // Return: integer
std::cout << typeid(config.value("name", "Default Name")).name() << std::endl; // Return: stl basic string
std::cout << typeid(config.value("precise", 0.0)).name() << std::endl; // Return: double
```

As you can see, it's automatically casting a valid data types for our keys.

Now, I would like to store these different type values in a `std::map` container. However, stl map do support only one data type:

```
enum TestEnum {
   TEST_MY_INTEGER_VALUE,
   TEST_NAME_OF_SOMETHING,
   TEST_PRECISE_VALUE,
}

std::map<TestEnum, (what I'm supposed to write here?)> values;
```

I did my research on this and it turns out that I could achieve this using `Boost.Variant` class, however my project is very small and I'd rather not use any frameworks for it. Only the pure C++11 methods.

**So, how could I store different return types that are being returned by the `value()` method into the map container?**

Comment: The type of `value("somename", default)` is determined by the type of `default` you pass, not by the actual type of the field named by `"somename"`. There's simply a bunch of overloads, and the second parameter determines which overload is called. `typeid` is a compile-time operator, its result cannot possibly depend on the actual JSon-encoded string you happen to parse at runtime.

Comment: In that library, `json` object stores a union of all possible value types; one of which is `std::map<std::string, json>` representing a JSon object (a map of property names to values). So basically, `json` is a limited implemenation of a `variant`, for a hard-coded set of types.

Comment: What you are saying is true, however I would not like to tie this question to the library (hence lack of tags regarding it). You can treat it as an example of multi-types I'd like to store. In general I'm looking for a solution for storing mixed types in a container. Types can also be `bool`, `int`, `std::string` as well as named structs. I think this would be possible using a struct with the template type, while I'm still reading regarding this, I will keep waiting for any answers on that.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any ,

Comment: @JesperJuhl Golden ;-) C++17 though.

Comment: @Kesse The solution to this is `std::variant` (or, for compilers not recent enough to support it, Boost.Variant) - but you ruled it out from the start. It's curious that you accepted it as answer, when you already knew about it and decided you didn't want it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well, accepted since apparently I'm not having many choices around. I did not want Boost but @knst gave a good solution to try a single-file variant implemenation for C++11. I think I can live with that ;-). In the end, I have no choice - either I will use `::variant` or it turns out I wont move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you able to use C++17, than you can use `std::variant`.

If using C++17 is impossible for you, than it is possible to use any small library instead Boost, for example [this](https://github.com/mpark/variant) implementation of `std::variant` for C++11/C++14.

And you can implement your own class type with same functionality of `std::variant`, but I strongly do not recommend it, because it is difficult to provide exception safety and another non-obviously cases.

For your simple case with only several types (`int`, `string`, `bool`, `float`) you could implement a several types `JsonInt`, `JsonString` and inherite it from common abstract class `JsonType`.